# rmarkdown python code chunk module matplotlib has no attribute pyplot

Tags: python, knitr, r-markdown

The following code works fine in Python 3:

```
$ ipython
.
.
.
In [1]: import pandas
   ...: 
   ...: my_data = pandas.read_csv("simplest.csv")
   ...: print(my_data)
   ...: 

      a     b     c
   0  1     3     5
   1  2     4     6
```

But if I put the same thing in a `python` code chunk in an R Markdown document and try to "knit" it, I get an error:

````
```{python simplest_py1}

import pandas

my_data = pandas.read_csv("simplest.csv")
print(my_data)
````

```

the `knit` step fails with the message:

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
Calls:  ... $.python.builtin.object -> py_get_attr -> py_get_attr_impl -> .Call
Execution halted

Note that (a) as I said above, this simple code works fine in plain `Python` (actually `iPython` in the example), and (b) the `Python` code is doing no graphical stuff whatsoever.  Hence, this is *not* a question about the use of `pyplot`, etc.  The question is: what is `knitr` trying to do with this code?

Comment: Do you use `RStudio` bundled with `Anaconda` or a standalone install on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know what causes the problem, but the problem disappears if I force rstudio to use the installed, 2.7 version of `Python`:

````
```{python, engine.path="/usr/bin/python"}
````

rather than trying to use my "personal" Anaconda version 3.